# HighCharts disable y-axis label notation

Tags: highcharts

How do I disable y-axis notation for HighCharts StockChart, it's showing as 7.5e-9 for the label:

```
Highcharts.stockChart
  yAxis: [{
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `enabled` property for labels to `false`.

```
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cek3407a/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.enabled

Comment: I meant to disable the notation so the numbers like this can be shown 0.0000000000000000, thank you!

Comment: Hi @Jimmy, Sorry for the misunderstanding. Use `formatter` function for the labels. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/95xsk81v/